# input text right beside logo bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, styles

Currently, I have the logo on the very left and rest of the stuff on the very right. The only issue I am having is that I want the search field to be right beside the logo on the right.

I have tried inserting it in the same div but it ends up coming right underneath it. Any help will be appreciated!

HTML:

```
<div class="top-nav">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" class="logo" />
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse ">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li id="search">
          <input class="search-input" placeholder="Search" type="text" />
          <a href="#">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="register-login"><a href="#">Login</a> \ <a href="#">Sign Up</a></div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x502t8zk/)**

Comment: Not sure why you have two `.nav` tags... That's the problem.

Comment: From the [Bootstrap examples](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/), Bootstrap provides a method for floating two navs, one left and one right.

Comment: Does this work? http://output.jsbin.com/gixevetaxe

Comment: @PraveenKumar yes

Comment: @user4756836 Can I put that as an answer and explain?

Comment: @PraveenKumar yes please

Comment: @user4756836 Done! `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer you replacing your code something like this:

```
<div class="top-nav">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" class="logo" />
      </a>
      <div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-collapse">
        <input class="search-input" placeholder="Search" type="text" />
        <a href="#">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
          <div class="register-login"><a href="#">Login</a> \ <a href="#">Sign Up</a></div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

I have added the `.nav` next to the logo from the `<li>`.

If the search icon goes out of area, use:

```
#search {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: the search icon going all the way right now.. not inside the textfield http://jsfiddle.net/x502t8zk/1/